# Young and inexperienced, I thought the task (seemed) easy

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

this one is from "The Element of Style."

Young and inexperienced, I thought the task easy.

I think it should be "young and inexperienced, I thought the task seemed easy."

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Either will do, with a slight difference of meaning.

*Think* can take a subcategorisation frame:

> think *object*  *adjectival-complement*

"I thought the task easy" means "I judged the task to be easy", which is similar to, but not quite the same as, your "I thought the task seemed easy".

Comment: Thank you Colin! (Should your punctuation marks, the commas and periods, be within the "?)

Comment: Think object adjectival-complement: Would 'think it through' be such an example?

Comment: @Student - (RE: the punctuation) – No, not on Mr. Fine's side of the [ocean](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/punctuation-errors-american-and-british-quotation-marks/).

Comment: B-Raising with _to be_-deletion. Very straightforward. _Seem_ is not involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

The “Young and inexperienced” part of the sentence means “I was young and inexperienced”.

The “I thought the task easy” part means either “I thought the task would be easy” or “I thought the task was easy”, depending on whether the speaker is reporting an expectation or an experience.

“I thought the task seemed easy” looks more appropriate as a statement of one's expectation about a task, than as a report of an experience.  After doing a task, one can say “The task was easy” or “The task was hard” depending on how hard it was to do the task.  But if a task is described to one, and someone else later asks how difficult the task should be, then saying “I thought the task seemed easy” means that when the task was described it sounded like an easy task.